# setting up versions using Eclipse, Maven, Git, Jenkins and Docker

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, docker, jenkins

I created a Docker container whose purpose is to run a Docker image that implements a REST API. The REST API is created with Java (using the Eclipse IDE, Maven and Spring Boot). When creating a jar file, it (jar file) is titled: workserver-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

The code is commited to a Gitlab server. When this takes place, a Jenkins job is created. The Jenkins job pulls down the code from the Gitlab Repository, creates a .jar file and then goes through the actions to turn the .jar file into a Docker image (or rather a .zip version of the Docker image).

"scp" is used move the zip file to a target system - where - the .zip file is unpacked (revealing the Docker image) and a container is started. The thing is, the Docker image being used has a version of "latest" (ex: imagename:latest).

I would like to use versions in this scenario starting with Eclipse (i.e. a pom.xml file holding a target workserver-2.2.13.jar file would eventually lead to Docker image that would be named imagename:2.3.13)

> I have seen here how one can assign a version number in Docker:
>   [Adding tags to docker image from jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569926/adding-tags-to-docker-image-from-jenkins)
>   I have also seen that one can use tags and version numbers in Git :
>   ex: git tag -a v2.5 -m 'Version 2.5' As mentioned above, the Maven
>   pom.xml file contains instructions to produce a .jar file called:
>   workserver-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

The system is working fine. I can commit a change in Eclipse and in a few minutes, a new version of the Docker container has been spun up on the delivery system - ready for use.

The issue I have now is setting up the version numbers.

Any guidance in this area would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [fabric8io docker maven plugin](https://dmp.fabric8.io/) to create the docker image using maven. This plugin allows you to build, run, and push docker images.

In particular, you can setup the name field in the plugin configuration to be:

```
<name>workserver:%l<name>
```

The %l will be resolved to the maven project version, which is the same as the jar version. You can run the plugin explicitly using:

```
mvn io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:build
```

Or you can set the packaging in the pom to be:

```
<packaging>docker-build</packaging>
```

This will build the image whenever you docker an `mvn package` and will push the image on `mvn deploy`