# Jenkins pipeline docker.push() gives error "docker tag" requires exactly 2 arguments

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'M trying to push the docker image built, onto private registry but encountering this error:

```html
Successfully built 6059208ca310
**Successfully tagged ubuntu:18.04**
[Pipeline] echo
Image Build
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker tag ubuntu:18.04 --build-arg PROXY_ADDRESS=http://proxy-random.net:3100 --build-arg my_image=ubuntu:18.04 x.some.com/ubuntu:18.04 --build-arg PROXY_ADDRESS=http://proxy-random.net:3100 --build-arg my_image=atpdml_pet_docker/ubuntu:ubuntu:18.04
"docker tag" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker tag --help'.

Usage:  docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]

Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Whereas I have not called docker tag anywhere in my pipeline.groovy, I suppose its a part of push(). My docker.build() uses --build-arg and require to push the tagged image (using either name in this case ubuntu:18.04 or the tag id 6059208ca310) onto the registry.

```html
def build_and_upload_image(dockerFileDir, imageName, imageTag) {
 script {
  dir(dockerFileDir) {
   docker.withRegistry('https://some.com','key') {
    def image = docker.build("${imageName}:${imageTag} --build-arg PROXY_ADDRESS=http://proxy-random.net:3100 --build-arg my_image=ubuntu:18.04")
    echo 'Image Build'
    image.push("ubuntu:18.04") ### even tried image.push() 
             image.push("latest")   
             echo 'image pushed'
   }
  }
 }
}

pipeline {
 agent{
  label 'docker-build'
 }
 stages {
  stage('Build format checker docker') {
   steps {
    build_and_upload_image("docker","ubuntu","18.04")
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need change

```
def image = docker.build("${imageName}:${imageTag} --build-arg PROXY_ADDRESS=http://proxy-random.net:3100 --build-arg my_image=ubuntu:18.04")
```

to

```
def image = docker.build("${imageName}:${imageTag}", "--build-arg PROXY_ADDRESS=http://proxy-random.net:3100 --build-arg my_image=ubuntu:18.04 .")
```

References:

1. [Jenkins Pipeline docker.build() gives error '"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998130/jenkins-pipeline-docker-build-gives-error-docker-build-requires-exactly-1-a)

Comment: I tries that way but it throws me the same docker tag error : + docker tag ubuntu:18.04 some.com/ubuntu:ubuntu:18.04 Error parsing reference: "some.com/ubuntu:ubuntu:18.04" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format .... My question is from where is it taking the tag info (i suppose from build) and can i modify and push it without it using the default tag info after the build step. example by specifying the tag id or tag name in the push(). thanks

Answer (score 0):

SO the first step was to change the syntax as mentioned by @Tarun Lalwani. After which it was a issue of tag (not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format), which I was able to resolve by mentioning the {env.BUILD_NUMBER} in the push() as mentioned in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53858257/7513466), although it does not take the tag name that was required but this does the job of pushing the image to the repo by its tag ID.